# Inequality on lengths and sums of vectors $\left\lVert\sum_i \vec{a_i}\right\rVert \le \sum_i \left\lVert \vec{a_i}\right\rVert$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm trying to show the following inequality, which expresses the fact that the magnitude of the sum of some vectors, is less than the sum of the individual magnitudes:
$$\left\lVert\sum_i \vec{a_i}\right\rVert \le \sum_i \left\lVert \vec{a_i}\right\rVert$$
I found this on a page with [Cauchy Schwarz](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/86174) problems, but stated without proof.

I've also be considered if it can be solved by induction, but I haven't got an idea how.

Comment: This sum has finite number of terms?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangle Inequality: $\|v+w\|\leq \|v\|+\|w\|$. Thus,
$$
\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v_i\|=\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} v_i+v_n\|\leq\| \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} v_i\|+\|v_n\|,
$$
then applies induction, i.e., $\| \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} v_i\|\leq  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \|v_i\|$.

Comment: Doh, you are right. I guess I was just specifically looking for a Cauchy Schwarz proof.

Comment: @ThomasAhle, Let $t=sign(\langle v, w\rangle)$, then 
$$\| v+tw\|^2=\| v\|^2+2t\langle v, w\rangle +\|w\|^2,$$ 
but $\|v+tw\|\let \|v\|+\|w\|$, then 
$$\|v+tw\|^2\leq\|v\|^2+2\|v\|\|w\| +\|w\|^2. $$
Thus 
$$t\langle v,w\rangle\leq \|v\|\|w\|$$
i.e., 
$$|\langle v,w\rangle|\leq \| v\|\|w\|.$$

Comment: @ThomasAhle, there is problem on to compile, but let $t=sign(\langle v,w\rangle)$, then $$|v+tw|^2=|v|^2+2t\langle v,w\rangle+|w|^2$$ but $|v+tw|\leq |v|+|t||w|\leq |v|+|w|$, then $$|v + tw|^2\leq |v|^2+2|v||w|+|w|^2.$$ Thus $$t\langle v,w\rangle=|\langle v,w\rangle|\leq |v||w|.$$